# Routes: one uri, two controllers. Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

So, there are the conflicting routes:

```
Route::get('{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->name('front.posts.show');
Route::get('{page:slug}', [PageController::class, 'show'])->name('front.pages.show');
```

I had an idea to unite them in one common controller and one method, but Post and Page are so different entities with their own additional methods and variables in `show()`. If I mix them, it will be a mess, that no one could ever understand. Maybe there is another way, perhaps with middleware somehow?

Comment: Give them appropriate route prefixes?

Comment: @Unflux can't do it, pure slug without anyting in url is essential condition.

Comment: Laravel doesn't facilitate this. You **could** define a middleware which checks if a model with the given slug exists and redirect to the appropriate controller accordingly, but I personally wouldn't. What if you get a post and a page with the same slug? Which do you return?

Comment: @Unflux it's not possible, slug has a validation. Rule checks, if it's unique for both tables, and a validation does not allow to save a page with post's slug, and the other way around. So, what about middleware, can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have no other option, but create common controller. It has three methods: `show($request)`, `showPost($post)` and `showPage($page)`. The last two are working as usual `show()` methods and return different views with different variables. Here is the main method, doing middleware job:

```
public function show($request)
{
    if (Post::where('slug', $request)->first()){
        $post = Post::where('slug', $request)->first();
        return $this->showPost($post);
    }

    if (Page::where('slug', $request)->first()){
        $page = Page::where('slug', $request)->first();
        return $this->showPage($page);
    }
    return abort('404');
}
```

And route:

```
Route::get('{slug}', [ResourceController::class, 'show'])->name('front.resource.show');
```

It's not the best way and not a good practice, but I don't know another variants. At least, it works.